# Error with trigger CreateAccountContact

Tags: apex, trigger, error

I tried to create a trigger to auto create a Contact when there is a new Account. I keep getting an error saying

> variable c doesn't exist

within the following code:

```
trigger CreateAccountContact on Account (after insert){
   List<Contact> ct = new List <Contact>();
   for(Account acc : trigger.new){
   if(acc.recordTypeID=='01224000000Da23'||'01224000000CrTk')
      Contact c = new Contact(LastName = acc.name,
                AccountId=acc.id,
                Fax=acc.Fax,
                MailingStreet=acc.BillingStreet,
                MailingCity=acc.BillingCity,
                MailingState=acc.BillingState,
                MailingPostalCode=acc.BillingPostalCode,
                MailingCountry=acc.BillingCountry,
                Address__c=acc.Address__c,
                Phone=acc.Phone,
                Email=acc.Email_address__c);
    ct.add(c);
insert ct;
}
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Enclose  condition in brackets:

```
    if(acc.recordTypeID=='01224000000Da23 '|| acc.recordTypeID=='01224000000CrTk')
    {
        Contact c = new Contact(LastName = acc.name,
                    AccountId=acc.id,
                    Fax=acc.Fax,
                    MailingStreet=acc.BillingStreet,
                    MailingCity=acc.BillingCity,
                    MailingState=acc.BillingState,
                    MailingPostalCode=acc.BillingPostalCode,
                    MailingCountry=acc.BillingCountry,
                    Address__c=acc.Address__c,
                    Phone=acc.Phone,
                    Email=acc.Email_address__c);
        ct.add(c);
    }
```

`if` only takes first statment when not enclosed in bracket. So `c` becomes out of scope for `ct.add(c)` becasue it is in second line.

Also, you must put `ct.add(c);` out of the `for` loop. It is not needed in `for`

Comment: Thanks! Although, now I am getting an error saying that OR operator can only be applied to Boolean expressions.

Comment: Use if(acc.recordTypeID=='01224000000Da23 '|| acc.recordTypeID=='01224000000CrTk')

Answer (score 1):

ALSO: You cannot do insert record in for loop you need to have insert outside for loop. This issue may be of brackets. You also need to get record type id from date base rather than hardcode here. try this may help you:

```
 List < Contact > ct = new List < Contact > ();
 for (Account acc: trigger.new) {
     if (acc.recordTypeID == '01224000000Da23' || '01224000000CrTk') {
         Contact c = new Contact(LastName = acc.name,
             AccountId = acc.id,
             Fax = acc.Fax,
             MailingStreet = acc.BillingStreet,
             MailingCity = acc.BillingCity,
             MailingState = acc.BillingState,
             MailingPostalCode = acc.BillingPostalCode,
             MailingCountry = acc.BillingCountry,
             Address__c = acc.Address__c,
             Phone = acc.Phone,
             Email = acc.Email_address__c);
         ct.add(c);
     }
 }
 insert ct;
```